# How to develop UI using same server instance (without restarting)

Tags: java, web-applications, spring, backend

I'm java developer. We developed good back end application. Customer asked UI part for it, but UI part development in our program needs each time restart the server (*to refresh WEB static files*). ***Is it possible develop UI without restarting back end with ability update WEB UI (js) libraries and files (css\js\html)?*** It could save a lot of time in my case. My web files do not refresh on server until application rebuilds and restarts (*web files are part of java build*). Articles about workarounds for tomcat are not useful i think, because we have upgraded the server part to spring boot (it provides java server with embedded WEB container).

I believe a lot of developers got same problem before, i tried solve my issue investigating forums but i did not find correspond situation.

Comment: If you have sufficient separation of concerns, you ought to be able to develop most or all of the UI without requiring a server at all.

Comment: You tell nothing tools about that i needs. But if you really want help me, you should. I know idea of separation development. This is reason why i asked how to follow this way!

Comment: How would I know that without knowing what technologies you are using?  Troubleshooting is off-topic here anyway.

Comment: _Spring boot_ is very helpful description, I thought. Possible i mistook, sorry, but you did not clarified my question also, isn't it!? Anyway it was very kind from your side try to help with suggestion. Thank you a lot for that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ...for web i used angular\css\html without special tools, but in weekend i have refactored it a lot adding **bower**, **grunt**, **jasmine** (i did not teach or use this technologies before, but seems i need them to have independent WEB UI with good WEB UI tests.)...

Comment: You did sort of bury the lead, didn't you?  I think you would have gotten better results if you'd described your environment up front and asked your question on the correct site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following logic we could have 2 solution ways:

1. IDE plugin to provide hot reload web content if java classes and js\css\html are packaged together (i did not find any working plugins for eclipse).
2. Start and debug independently java web container & web UI.

I'm going to describe with more details 2nd way (it seems most comfortable for big applications):

- to debug java server each IDE (eclipse, netbeans, idea, sts, JBoss Tools...) provides a lot of abilities. And almost each tool can recompile and reload java classes in run time. So java server side can swap classes in run time without problems.
- WEB part seeps also not hard, **BUT** i never did it before so I have got a lot of difficulties...:

---

- (independent web application) *dependency issue - have been solved using bower*
- (independent web application) *web context hot reload files issue - have been solved solved using grunt*
- IDE issue - *i stopped my choice on **text sublime** (but i'm not sure that i did best choice)*
- test issue - for UI is solved also in easy way (*using jasmine or other js test tools*) - it was new for me.

As result I can now reload files web files in very fast way. But I never worked with *sublime*, possible i need more special plugins to check my js\css and so on. I feel WEB UI can be developed in more easier way if comfortable plugin or tool (*i do not know how to check all plugins that i have installed or so i can not share this information now.* I know I have installed something for checking & formatting js\css\html\angular, and my autocomplete works time to time...).

I hope experts will add more recommendations & details to my answer (which **WEB UI IDE** would be better to use or which plugins I need to feel myself comfortable with sublime...).

---

***P.S.***
My investigation have taken almost three days after question have been published and near week before that time. I've got a lot of important information **BUT** I need much more than I got. It would be very helpful if someone recommend me good book(s) \ article(s) \ example(s) \ suggestions and so on.